# Canon printer not printting .tiff files at the correct size

Tags: printing, tiff

I am trying to print a `.tiff` file. The original `.tiff` file is **3.5cm** but when I print it out with my **Canon MG6300** printer it comes out as **2.5cm**. I am printing to **A4**.

I hope this is in the right place and that I've given enough information. I've tried googling this but had no luck.

Comment: Have you read the manual for the printer and the software you used to print with? Doing that will show you how to print at whatever size your printer can handle, whether it be 3.5cm or larger than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say this is most likely happening because either:

1. the software you are using to print the image is scaling it down prior to sending it to the printer
   or
2. the selected printer driver settings are set to scale down the image before printing

If I were to guess, I'd say it was the first option.

Digital images are made of pixels, which don't have a fixed conversion to real world units of length. When you say that the `.tiff` file is **3.5cm** what this will mean is that the file has information stored in its metadata that defines it's resolution per inch/cm such that it would print at that size, if the printing application takes said information into account.

Your likely issue is that some programs may default to resizing an image, say if it's too big to fit on the page area that a printer can handle.

For example, if I open an 'A4' `.tiff` file (2480x3508pixels at 300ppi) in [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/) and hit print, it'll print out slightly smaller than A4. My printer can't print right to the edge of the paper, so [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/) scales down the image so it'll all fit (overriding the 300ppi setting in the images metadata).

Recommend you check the print settings in the application you're using to print the image and look for an option like `scale` (should be 100%) or `width` `hight` values and check they're what you're expecting.

If you can't find a solution to your issue there (or anything in your printer preferences about `scaling`, `Reduce/Enlarge Document` or similar), then provide more information about exactly what software you're using to print the image, and someone familiar with it may be able to provide specific instructions.